# Showing the latest changes of each subdirectory in git

Tags: git, github

In [github](http://github.com) if you open a repository you will see a page showing the latest commit and time of each subdirectory and file.

Can I do this by command line in git?

Comment: @kirelagin `git log` lists commits, not files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell you could create a script like this

```
git ls-tree --name-only HEAD | ForEach-Object { 
   Write-Host $_ "`t" (git log -1 --format="%cr`t%s" $_)
}
```

This loops through all files in the current directory, writes out the file name, a tab (the backquoted "t"), and then the output of `git log` with the relative date, a tab, and the commit message.

Sample output:

```
subfolder        18 hours ago   folder for miscellaneous stuff included
foo.txt          3 days ago     foo is important
.gitignore       3 months ago   gitignore added
```

The GitHub result actually contains the committer too, you can get that also by adding `[%cn]`:

```
Write-Host $_ "`t" (git log -1 --format="%cr`t%s`t[%cn]" $_)
```

The script above does not handle long filenames well, since it depends on tabs. Here is a script that creates a nicely formatted table, where each column is exactly as wide as it needs to be:

```
git ls-tree --name-only HEAD | ForEach-Object { 
  Write-Output ($_ + "|" + (git log -1 --format="%cr|%s" $_)) 
} | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Name = $_.Split('|')[0]
    Time = $_.Split('|')[1]
    Message = $_.Split('|')[2]
  }
} | Format-Table -Auto -Property Name, Time, Message
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great. I'm using Linux actually, but I think the idea should be similar.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks answers from Klas Mellbourn and Nevik Rehnel, finally I combined these two versions into mine:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=`ls -A`
MAXLEN=0
for f in $FILES; do
    if [ ${#f} -gt $MAXLEN ]; then
        MAXLEN=${#f}
    fi
done
for f in $FILES; do
    str=$(git log -1 --format="%cr      [%cn]   %s" $f)
    printf "%-${MAXLEN}s -- %s\n" "$f" "$str"
done
```

Outputs:

```
$ bash view.bash
android_webview   -- 4 months ago       [boxxx@chromium.org]    Disable testCalledForIframeUnsupportedSchemeNavigations
ash               -- 4 months ago       [osxxxx@chromium.org]   Rename _hot_ -> _hover_
cc                -- 4 months ago       [enxx@chromium.org]     cc: Let impl-side painting use smaller tiles
chrome            -- 5 weeks ago        [Deqing]     Set the nacl pipe to non-blocking
tools             -- 10 weeks ago       [Haxx Hx]    Add submodule tools/gyp
```

Comment: really nice! I modified it a bit here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17361406/846273

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in a single Git command for all the entries in the CWD, but with a simple bash script, you can:

Put

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=`ls -A`
MAXLEN=0
for f in $FILES; do
    if [ ${#f} -gt $MAXLEN ]; then
        MAXLEN=${#f}
    fi
done
for f in $FILES; do
    printf "%-${MAXLEN}s -- %s\n" "$f" "$(git log --oneline -1 -- $f)"
done
```

in a file and run it as a script, or use it as an online command by running
`FILES=$(ls -A); MAXLEN=0; for f in $FILES; do if [ ${#f} -gt $MAXLEN ]; then MAXLEN=${#f}; fi; done; for f in $FILES; do printf "%-${MAXLEN}s -- %s\n" "$f" "$(git log --oneline -1 -- $f)"; done` on a bash prompt directly.

Comment: You can get all versioned files with e.g. `git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD`, then you can use the printf function on that list.

Comment: @steabert: but that includes neither untracked files of the repo nor the commit which last changed them or its date.

Comment: @Deqing, works for me; **how** does it "not work" for you? do you get an error? does it print something wrongly?

Comment: It prints `" "$f" "$(git log --oneline -1 -- $f)"` as bash prompt, and looks like showing the right commits, but quite slow comparing to the script way.

Comment: that's very odd; the two versions are exactly the same, except for newlines to improve readability. but if you want to use this regularly, putting it in a script to call it with a single command is probably more useful anyway

Comment: @Nevik: the command in the comment is only to get a list of versioned files, as I thought was clear from the fact that I said you should still use a print function on that. Why would you want untracked files, they have no commit date or anything? Also, if you want to get everything, you can just `find .` in the top directory and get all files from that instead of just those in the `$PWD`.

Comment: so something like `for file in $(git ls-tree -r HEAD|awk '{print $4}'); do echo $file; git log --format="%cr %s" -1 $file; done | less`