# Git: Show last commit date and message for each file in directory like Github

Tags: git, github

In Github, when browsing a directory using the web interface, one can see when each file and subdirectory was last committed in addition to its commit message.

How would you do the same thing using the `git` command line interface?

Comment: type `git log --help` and read through the output formatting options

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok, I modified [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17105008/846273) a bit to produce a nicer format. Here's the result in ZSH

[image]

And here's the script

```
#!/bin/sh

FILES="$(git ls-tree --name-only HEAD .)"
MAXLEN=0
IFS="$(printf "\n\b")"
for f in $FILES; do
    if [ ${#f} -gt $MAXLEN ]; then
        MAXLEN=${#f}
    fi
done
for f in $FILES; do
    str="$(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%C(green)%cr%Creset %x09 %C(cyan)%h%Creset %s %C(yellow)(%cn)%Creset" $f)"
    printf "%-${MAXLEN}s -- %s\n" "$f" "$str"
done
```

Here's the [gist source](https://gist.github.com/Gabro/5883819)

Comment: I'd suggest using `git ls-files` instead of `ls -A` so that you only get the files track by Git.

Comment: good suggestion, since I don't want to make it recursive I ended up using `git ls-tree --name-only HEAD .`

Comment: I'm curious what the differences are, could you elaborate?

Comment: run it on a directory and you will see :) `git ls-files` will show every file in the repo, while I'd like to show only the current directory

Comment: Ah, I see. `git ls-files -- .` will probably do the same thing, but I don't think it has any advantages over the way you've done it.

Comment: actually it doesn't. I couldn't find a way to make it work with `ls-files`, that's why I opted for `ls-tree`. Thank you for the pointer in any case ;)

Comment: This looks great! I thought that there would be a built-in `git` command (probably in `git log`) that would take care of it, but this works just as well too.

Comment: could you re-link "this answer" link to the answer not the png?

Comment: @Christian whoops! Bad copy & paste... Thank you, now it points to the answer ;)

Comment: This won't work with files which has spaces in it. $FILES array is split on spaces..

Comment: I end up using this which works on files with spaces: git ls-files --exclude-standard -z | while read -r -d '' f; do

    strDate=$(git log -1 --decorate --pretty=format:%ci "$f")
    strUser=$(git log -1 --decorate --pretty=format:%cn "$f")
    printf "$f;$strDate;$strUser\r" >> files-semicomma.csv 
done

Comment: To handle filenames that include spaces the script just needs to set IFS so that the for loops iterate over the newline separator. So add the following before the for loops: IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

Comment: @patthoyts thank you, I just noticed this and updated the script!

Comment: Thanks for the script, very handy! To avoid having to put the script where you're using it I propose adding cd "$1" before the first line of code :) Most people can probably add that themselves, but there's no real loss in trying to upstream it ;)

Comment: @NegatioN you can put the script anywhere (I have it in `$HOME/bin`), then run it from within the project as any other git command. If you name the script `git-something` you can also run it as `git something` ;)

Comment: Of course... That's equally smart, or smarter... :D

Comment: How can I limit the for loop here to omit files of a certain type? for example, suppose I'm only interested in seeing the .md files in the directories, not the .png files?

Comment: Fails if files `not in the working tree`.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Wonderful script. One issue, I am not getting the colored output, what could be the reason? As such pretty format color output is working on my shell. Like output of this `git log -1 --pretty=format:"%C(green)%cr"` on the shell is colored.

Comment: If it fails because you have Unicode characters in the filename and they are escaped as `\nnn`, you can configure Git to show them normally using `git config core.quotepath off` .

Answer (score 2):

I use the following line:

`git log --decorate=full --pretty=full --graph -b --stat`

You should put it in your `.gitconfig` as an alias (Perso, I use `git l` for this.)

Comment: It looked good at first, but it only shows which files have been edited per commit. I think the OP meant something different: he wants to know which is the last commit that affected every object in the working copy.

Comment: Ok, `git log <path>` works.

Comment: Does it? Doesn't look like

Comment: Sure. The output is not nicer but: `for i in `git ls-files . | sed -e 's#/.*##' | uniq`; do git log --pretty=format:"$i: %h %an %s" -n1 -- "$i" ; done`

Comment: ok it's basically the same thing the script I modified does, just condensed in a single line ;) I.e. you have to call two git commantds: one for listing and for logging on each file. There's no straight  magic git command for that

Comment: My first version was `for i in $(ls -A); do echo "$i: $(git log $i -n1); done` No more than `git log`. Without `$()` for portability issues. No more than shell tricks.

Comment: @Vash2593 -- and thus, the [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17361406/1048186). But your comment is helpful in convincing me that I really needed to get a script like that other answer's.