# How to get last commit information for all files under a folder

Tags: git

I want to get last author, last commit date, last commit message of all files under a folder, just like the file list information of GitHub website, or [Gitlab website](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/tree/master/src). I know I can use git log to get the information one by one for all files, but I think it's not efficient, is there any git command can get the information for all files more efficient?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359370/git-show-last-commit-date-and-message-for-each-file-in-directory-like-github)?

Comment: “is there any git command can get the information for all files more efficient [than git-log]?”—According to `man git` under “Interrogators” it looks like there is no such command.